# Golang: cannot use sql.NamedArg in prepared statement

Tags: mysql, sql, go, amazon-aurora

I have a query that is using NamedArgs from the sql.DB and I'm getting an error when building

```
cannot use args (type []sql.NamedArg) as type []interface {} in argument to stmt.Exec
```

The example in the SQL library shows it being used:

```
Example usage:
    db.ExecContext(ctx, `
     delete from Invoice
     where
     TimeCreated < @end
     and TimeCreated >= @start;`,
     sql.Named("start", startTime),
     sql.Named("end", endTime),
    )
```

The only difference is that I'm currently using a prepared statement `stmt` and calling the `Exec` method on that. I've created a slice of NamedArg with my values and it's using the `...` expander.

```
res, err := stmt.Exec(args...)
```

What exactly is wrong when the example shows the `sql.Named()` method call directly in the code? Why wouldn't an expanded slice work?

Comment: MySQL (and therefore Aurora) does not support named parameters, it only supports positional parameters with the `?` placeholder. I suppose `sql.NamedArg` is for use with Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how passing arguments to a variadic function works in Go. You either pass the individual values which can be of any type, or you pass in a slice whose **element type matches exactly that of the variadic parameter** and follow it with `...`.

I.e. you can either do:

```
res, err := stmt.Exec(
    sql.Named("start", startTime),
    sql.Named("end", endTime),
)
```

or you can do:

```
args := []interface{}{
    sql.Named("start", startTime),
    sql.Named("end", endTime),
}
res, err := stmt.Exec(args...)
```